# Play a song 3 times using a batch file on VLC

Tags: loops, batch-file, vlc, audio-player

I'm a beginner in this script, even though I know some basic vanilla JS. I want to make a batch file that could run 3 times...

Here is what I have tried, batch file just runs and closes. I'm not sure why this happens? Can I make it work?

```
@echo off 
for /l %%v in (1,1,3) do (
set "file=AKАТИСТ светом Архангелу МИХАИЛУ - AKATIST.mp3"
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("VLCplayer.xspf"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "D:\AKАТИСТ светом Архангелу МИХАИЛУ - AKATIST.mp3"
  echo Sound.settings.volume = 76
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo While Sound.playState ^<^> 1
  echo Wend
  run Sound
)
)
```

Comment: and what? what happens when you run it? why is that wrong? you didn't ask any question.

Comment: Nothing happens, I wanted to run the song 3 times.

Comment: Why would anything happen, when all you did is `echo`, never actually ran anything?

Comment: I see. How do I make it run the URL I entered? :/

Comment: Have you tried actually executing those commands, instead of just `echo`ing them...?

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I'll try...

Comment: You should also open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output. You should notice that `for ... /l` is not valid syntax for the command you are using.I would assume that you're supposed to be `echo`ing your commands to a file, and then running an executable file with that file as an input for those commands to be understood, because they are not batch file commands.

Comment: I've removed it from the code

Comment: I've edited the URL, and added `run` at the end, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: `Set Sound = CreateObject("VLCplayer.xspf"^)` is not a batch command and will never work. As the rest of your code depends on that line working, none of it will work either.

Comment: It looks like you found that code online but only kind of skimmed it when you copied it and you missed the part where that middle bit is vbscript and you have to redirect it to a VBS file and then use `cscript` to execute _that_ file.

Comment: Also, you don't need _any_ of that code to play a song in VLC. Just call VLC and pass the audio file name as an argument.

Comment: `run` is not a batch file command.